# I could not perform the output of the value written to the input at the bottom

Tags: javascript

I want to see the input in a project and get the output at the same time. They did this only in the so-called way. But I want the output of my buttonless post. how to do?

```
<input type="text" id="myText">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

  
<script>
  
// Here the value is stored in new variable x 
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: you mean while use is typing in the input, you want to show input's value in the `#demo` element ?

Comment: yes, it was a better explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to add an EventListener so every time the input changes the function will run.

Just add the following, I think it will work fine.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', myFunction);
```

So on every key pressed the x variable will be assigned the current input.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your goal by using [input_event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) on the `input` tag, like this:

```js
let demo = document.getElementById('demo');
document.getElementById('myText').addEventListener('input',function(){
  demo.innerHTML= this.value;
})
```

```css
#demo{ 
  background: #eee;
  min-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText">
<p id="demo"></p>
```